# What would you recommend using for audio file transcribing into a .txt?

Tags: audio, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, transcription

I am working on a small school project where I have to take a lot of audio files and transcribe them into .txt files. I am a beginner at programming.
So far I've tried [alexkras](https://www.alexkras.com/transcribing-audio-file-to-text-with-google-cloud-speech-api-and-python/) method using Google's Cloud Speech API. But I can't use this for mass transcribing as it is done by converting the audio to .wav using an external software(This can be done through ffmpeg too so not a big deal) and splitting up the new .wav file into <60s parts as Cloud Speech can only transcribe <60s at a time which is a big loss in trans unless you upload them to GCS but this is also a problem for mass transcribing as some .wav files are large enough(A 1 hour podcast I used turned into 800mb file) the process is slowed down.

The next one I tried is using gcloud SDK and directly transcribing audio files on the GCS using a small code in my terminal, now the problem I observed here is the transcription is not complete and it shows the transcription this way,

Example from Google:

```
   {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse",
      "results": [
        {
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.9840146,
              "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Which is not ideal, maybe there is a way to transfer it into a text file but the transcriptions I've done so far are not complete, I got like a total of <30 lines of text from a 11-minute video.

The most effective method I've tried is the alexkras method but as I've said above there are problems with that too(In my case). I've been looking into Machine Learning methods for speech-to-text so it can recognise or transcribe audios with accent too.

Do you guys know any method to help me transcribe mass audios into text effectively? It would have been so happy with alexkras method if it wasn't for the splitting of files or uploading it to GSC. I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions or guidance with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the Watson STT API, the file/stream size limitation is 100MBs, which means that if using the proper encoding you can decode files up to several hours long. You can use `sox` or `ffmpeg` for the audio conversion if needed, the lighter weight codec is `audio/ogg`

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/#recognize_sessionless12

see the curl example to get you started

Comment: But there is only 100min per month limit on the free version.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been exploring the [AWS Transcribe product](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/).   It requires an AWS account, which can be obtained free, with a credit card for payment if you go over the free limits.

It provides up to 60 minutes per month of audio transcription.  If you go beyond 60 minutes of audio, you'll need to pay a bit less than $1.50 per hour of audio transcribed.

The transcription results in a .JSON file that is not easy to read.  But, there is a [php script on GitHub](https://github.com/purdy/aws-transcribe-transcript) that turns the .JSON file into a very easy-to-read transcript.

I've found it to be pretty accurate, and relatively easy to use.  I'd look into it if I were you.